# Battery monitor for LXDE in Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, power-management, lxde

I have Arch Linux plus LXDE installed in my laptop. I want to know the status of the battery level. I tried to install `batterymon`, but got too many errors that I couldn't decipher.

Is there any other way to monitor the battery level?

Comment: what is you laptop model ?

Comment: its an hcl it was bought in 2008.

Comment: If you couldn't decipher these errors, all the more reason to **copy-paste the error messages into your question** and we'll decipher them for you.

Comment: this is the error file. http://pastebin.com/EcHKq65y

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to get it is through acpi command as follows (note acpi may not be installed by default so use apt-get or yum command to install the same):

```
$ acpi -V
```

or from the /proc fs

```
[root@centos ~]# cat /proc/acpi/battery/BAT0/*
alarm:                   unsupported
present:                 yes
design capacity:         50000 mWh
last full capacity:      50000 mWh
battery technology:      rechargeable
design voltage:          10000 mV
design capacity warning: 100 mWh
design capacity low:     50 mWh
capacity granularity 1:  1 mWh
capacity granularity 2:  1 mWh
model number:            1
serial number:           0
battery type:            VBOX
OEM info:                innotek
present:                 yes
capacity state:          ok
charging state:          charged
present rate:            0 mW
remaining capacity:      50000 mWh
present voltage:         10000 mV
[root@centos ~]#
```

Aside, I found this bug link which says lxpanel has got problems on Fedora with ACPI stack and it mucks the states.  https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=561311

There is another utility on sourceforge.net called [webattery](http://sourceforge.net/projects/webattery/) , perhaps worth a try.
and another one jupiterapp, a tray app http://www.jupiterapplet.org/

Comment: Is there a tray app that will be more useful.

Comment: Arch uses `pacman` as a package manager...

Comment: this is seemingly fixed in fedora core 16, issue with lxde panel battery app.

Comment: perhaps, use jupiter applet then. http://www.jupiterapplet.org/

Comment: installed webattery,but i guess it'll take time to install jupiter as writing pkgbuild is very new to me

Comment: There is already a PKGBUILD in AUR: http://aur.archlinux.org/packages.php?ID=43821

Comment: installed jupiter successfully from the PKGBUILD.users having awesome should upgrade their cairo package as well. The cairo and cairo-xcb are conflicting packages and new cairo has xcb in it.

Comment: awesome..yippie!! my one more upvote for recommending jupiterapp ;-)

Answer (score 1):

There are any number of tools to monitor your battery's state: you could install something like [conky](http://conky.sourceforge.net/) to display it on your desktop, or you could use ACPI, as described in the [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/ACPI_modules).

The real issue you have is that if you do not understand, or are unwilling to try to resolve, the error messages when installing a simple application, then you are going to encounter far more difficult issues running Arch.

Answer (score 1):

try installing acpi, and running acpi -b :)

then you can put the data directly to the conky or something, using: `acpi -b | sed -r 's/.*([0-9]{2,3}%).*/\1/'`